# What is the equivalent constant for C++ NULL in Delphi?

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi

I need to migrate my C++ codes to Delphi. There are many checks to check if a given  handle(`HANDLE`) is `NULL` or not in C++ codes. What is the equivalent constant that can be used in Delphi? It seems that `null` in Delphi is different from `NULL` in C++.

Comment: Instead of checking [`Null`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Null) values, you should `try` and `catch` exceptions thrown... since *Null* is a *no* according to your question...

Comment: @Ruks Don't think so. I can only assume that `HANDLE` means we are talking about winapi which does not use exceptions to indicate errors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the Windows C++ header files, `NULL` is a macro that expands to `0`. This means that `NULL` can be used in both numeric and pointer contexts, because the C++ language supports such usage.

However, for Delphi, the value `0` is used in numeric contexts, and the value `nil` is used in pointer contexts.

Windows `HANDLE` values are declared in Delphi as numeric types and so in place of C++ `NULL` you should use `0` in Delphi.

Comment: @George: In the windows headers, it's 0.

Comment: @George The reference to `HANDLE` makes me believe that we are talking about `NULL` from the Windows headers

Comment: @Bathsheba David Heffernan Ah yep sorry, ready for the weekend :).